# TransactionTooLargeException when startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I have an Android app that is failing in devices with 1GB of RAM.

I'm getting TransactionTooLargeException when opening activities with `startActivityForResult`. If a change them to `startActivity` it works but I need the result of those activities.

I follow some suggestions like the following but it didn't work for me:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle oldInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(oldInstanceState);
        oldInstanceState.clear();
    }
```

An important comment is that I'm not getting any information from the backend, so it's not a large json file which is causing this.

Also the intent is very simple:

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OtherPaymentAddActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("isAdd", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.OTHER_PAYMENT_ADDED);
                break;
```

Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Here you have the LogCat

```
    Event recorded: Event{appId='com.payment.collection', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainFragmentManager, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=-1269867677418891571, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=CheckAddActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-1269867677418891570}]}
05-28 13:20:57.631 2291-3874/com.google.android.gms V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3362813
    Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
05-28 13:20:57.632 2291-3874/com.google.android.gms V/FA: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
    Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 3362813
05-28 13:20:57.635 2291-3874/com.google.android.gms V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 8
05-28 13:20:58.004 3564-3564/com.payment.collection E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 523184)
05-28 13:20:58.004 3564-3564/com.payment.collection D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
05-28 13:20:58.007 3564-3564/com.payment.collection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.payment.collection, PID: 3564
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 523184 bytes
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3752)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 523184 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3606)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3744)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
05-28 13:20:58.011 1615-1863/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.payment.collection/.MainActivities.CheckAddActivity
05-28 13:20:58.055 1615-1683/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-28 13:20:58.055 1615-1683/system_process D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-28 13:20:58.056 1615-1683/system_process W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVE
```

Comment: You might want to edit your question and post the entire stack trace along with the error message, in case that gives us any clues. BTW, in your opening sentence, I think you mean 1GB of RAM. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare please find now the log

Comment: Don't persist Bitmap into `savedInstanceState`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce where are you seeing that? I need to maintain this app that was not built by me, and as you can see I'm not an expert in Android... Did you get any clue about a bitmap in the logs or is just an advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end, it was that I was sending in a Bundle to a Fragment a list of items as serializable that contains like 3K items, it were not complex items, just Objects with some properties...

So, I re adjust the logic to avoid having to do that. As a lesson learnt, attention to what you put in:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("list", itemList);
```